# Migrate Liferay Database TO HSQL

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, hsqldb

on the web there are many resources about exporting a development database (HSQL) into a production one (eg. MySQL), but I need to move data in the opposite way.

I usually use the Liferay embedded function to export data to a new database, but it needs for a running database server instance (and it seems to be impossible using HSQL).

Does a way to achieve this goal exist in Liferay 6.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Control Panel / Server Administration / Data Migration. You can give the standard HSQL URLs - you don't need a running HSQL server. The standard HSQL parameters can be found in Liferay's [portal.properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#JDBC) under Hypersonic